# Visualforce <apex:actionFunction> Issue. Why Oncomplete attribute is executing first than rerender?

Tags: salesforce, apex, execution, visualforce, rerender

VF Page:
This is my pagination in VF:

```
`<apex:repeat value="{!paginationNumbers}" var="pageNumber">
<li class="page-item" id="pageItem{!pageNumber}" >
<a class="page-link" onclick="paginationFilter(this)">{!pageNumber}</a>
</li>
</apex:repeat> `
```

Onclick it is calling a paginationFilter method which is like this:

```
`function paginationFilter(clickedElement) {
   clickedButton = clickedElement;
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
   var value = clickedElement.innerText;
   console.log(value);
        
   paginationControllerMethod(value);
 }`
```

this paginationControllerMethod(value); is calling a Apex method by using apex:actionfunction:

```
<apex:actionfunction name="paginationControllerMethod" action="{!pagination}" rerender="pagination" oncomplete="anotherFunction()">
    <apex:param name="value" value="value" assignTo="{!paginationNumber}" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

after calling the apex method it should first rerender the component and then call the anotherfunction. but I guess another function is executing first and then rerendering is happening.

Another function:

```
`function anotherFunction() {
   var value = clickedButton.innerText;

   // Remove 'active' class from all elements with class 'page-item'
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('page-item');
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');
   }
        
   console.log(clickedButton);
   // Add 'active' class to the clicked element
   clickedButton.parentElement.classList.add('active');
 }`
```

if i remove pagination from rerender then clicked button becomes active. another method is working fine but the execution between rerender and oncomplete is not as expected as it should be.
I want rerender should execute first then the oncomplete attribute execute later.